# Template Validation Error - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed:

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, pester

I am having a bit of trouble deploying the template below:

[azuredeploy.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbbmP.jpg)

One of the error message that has thrown:

> 'The template resource '[concat('nsg-create',copyIndex())]' at line '344' and column '9' is invalid. The api-version '2016-07-01' used to deploy the template does not support 'ResourceGroup' property. Please use api-version '2017-05-10' or later to deploy the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.

Code that have been used to deploy.

```
 Context "Template Validation" {

    It "Template $here\azuredeploy.json and parameter file  passes validation" -TestCases $ParameterFileTestCases {
        Param( $ParameterFile )
        Update-Module -Name AzureRM -Force
        $output = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $TempValidationRG -Force -Mode Complete -TemplateFile "$here\azuredeploy.json" -TemplateParameterFile "$here\$ParameterFile"  -ErrorAction Stop 5>&1
        $output.ProvisioningState | Should -Be "Succeeded"
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the API version, however, that still gave me the same error. I do not understand how to solve this issue. 
I am trying to test the template through pester.

The output of Get-Module AzureRM* -ListAvailable  : 
[AzureRM list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGeCl.jpg)

Comment: Could you include the relevant JSON in the question (not in a screenshot)?

Comment: also, does the template works when you deploy it manually\powershell (not pester)

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes the template does work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another api-version. Try `2017-05-10` this one.

Also, try updating the Azure Powershell to latest version.

Comment: Your template is fine - this will be the apiVersion used by the tool doing deployment - as Gleb mentions, update your PowerShell cmdlets

Comment: I have changed the API version, it still did not work.  @bmoore-msft

Comment: I have also tried to update the Azure Powershell with this Update-Module -Name AzureRM -Force. Please correct me if there is another way to do it. @4c74356b41

Comment: add the output of `Get-Module AzureRM* -ListAvailable` to the question

Comment: Done @4c74356b41

Comment: I suggest you update azure powershell modules, yours are outdated, if `-force` doesnt for you, just delete them under /program files/windowspowershell/modules, reboot and do install-module azurerm